# Problems connecting to internet (by ethernet) after updating to Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, ethernet

About three days ago, I started experiencing problems with my PC's ethernet connection when it was still using Windows 7.  After turning off energy efficient ethernet, my connection briefly resumed just long enough for me to download and install Windows 10.  However, since updating to Windows 10, I have been unable to connect to the internet.  The connection functions normally for all other computers on both Windows 7 and Windows 10.  My PC is a home built desktop with specifications that should certainly be able to run Windows 10 - I can be more specific if this is an important detail.

I have been trying just about every solution I have found online.  I apologize for the length of the post, but I think it could be a good challenge for someone with more knowledge than me.  Here are the steps I took:

1. Ran the troubleshooter: this returned a number of errors every time I ran it.  After running the troubleshooter, my internet connection would briefly say "Network: Connected", but after a few second, it would revert to "Network: No Connected".  The errors would (seemingly randomly) cycle between ""Ethernet" doesn't have a valid IP Configuration (fixed)", "The default gateway is not available (fixed)", and "The connection between your access point, router, or cable modem and the internet is broken (detected)" - the last error was rarest and most inconsistently found after running it about ~50 times).
2. Renewing my IP/DNS address: I tried running ipconfig /release (successful) followed by an ipconfig /renew.  Every time I try to run /renew, I am faced with "An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet: unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out.".  In response to this, I tried running ipconfig /registerDNS, which initially said it would initiate registration and report errors in Event Viewer.  The action did not change anything, and I noticed multiple errors in Event Viewer concerning the DHCP-Client that "Your computer was not able to renew its address from the network...error 0x79".
3. Resetting IP/TCP: I ran both netsh winsock reset (successfully) and netsh int ip reset.  Running the second command had about 15-20 lines of successful resetting, but I believe it may be an important detail that the last 2 lines said "Resetting, failed. / Access is denied."
4. I do not have any external antiviruses, and turning off Windows Firewall did nothing.
5. I fully reinstalled Windows 10, did a network reset, and reinstalled my network adapter's drivers.  I was still unable to connect to the internet.
6. I ensured that the power management setting for the network adapter did not allow the computer to turn off the adapter to save power.

If you read this far, I really appreciate you taking the time to help out a stranger on the internet.  The fact that I was experiencing a similar problem on Windows 7 with none of the above solutions working, except for turning off energy efficient ethernet, gives me hope that this problem may be able to be solved.  I appreciate any advice/methods/info that anyone can offer, and please let me know if you need additional information.

I believe that the errors associated with the ipconfig commands /renew and /registerDNS may be the best place to start, but I do not have the knowledge to troubleshoot any further.  In addition, I have not found a similar question online where someone ran the troubleshooter and it would continually "fix" (but not actually provide connectivity) the connection with the same few error messages.

Comment: if you boot a linux live-CD on it, does that work fine? that would at least eliminate upstream network config issues or cabling failures. That said though, if you have reinstalled completely, either you are doing somthing wrong repeatedly (which is unlikely using a default config; PCs these days practically network themselves) or you have a hardware problem. I would check the RAM with memtestx86 and the MS ram tester, but I've had more than one motherboard die ungracefully, causing random errors and problems that have no solutions. mabey try swapping out the nic; they're cheap. Good luck.

Comment: As @FrankThomas state, a good test whether it's hardware or software (OS) at fault is to create a live Linux USB flash drive, and boot directly from that without even having to install it on HDD, about an hour total to create and boot from it. If that works, you know it's Windows at fault... then decide if you want to reinstall yet again or install the alternate OS. See https://itsfoss.com/create-live-usb-of-ubuntu-in-windows/, for example.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am hesitant to point to a hardware issue because although there was an initial problem when I was using Windows 7, I was able to fix it by changing one setting (EEE).  The problem is now constant with Windows 10, though.  I will let you know how the Linux boot goes for me, appreciate the advice.

Comment: All hardware dies someday, the question is, was it Yesterday, or Tomorrow?

Answer (score 0):

The basic troubleshooting that you could try is:

First of all do:

```
ipconfig /flushdns     (clean local DNS cache)
ipconfig /release
ipconfig /renew
```

Check if your network adapter it's working fine:

```
ping 127.0.0.1 -t
```

Check if your machine is going out to internet:

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -t
```

Check if your machine is solving DNS:

```
ping google.com -t
```

See if the DNS is working fine with OpenDNS IP address to solve the name amazon.com:

```
nslookup amazon.com 208.67.222.222
```

Try pathping and mtr ([details here](https://www.clouddirect.net/knowledge-base/KB0011455/using-traceroute-ping-mtr-and-pathping)) to see what return.

Comment: The issue I was experiencing with ipconfig was part of the reason why I wanted to get some more information.  When I use ipconfig /renew, I get the error "An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet: unable to contact your DHCP server. Request has timed out."  In addition, the network adapter appears to be functioning properly, but all of the other tests failed, any thoughts on what this means?  Wondering if it is a hardware problem, so I will definitely follow some other advice concerning a Linux test.

Comment: https://www.poftut.com/windows-ipconfig-command-tutorial-examples-list-change-renew-ip-configuration/
These are specific command about ipconfig, Could you put the output of them in the post? (1-6)